# Inclusions of CW-complexes are cofibrations.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Has the inclusion from the $ (n - 1) $-sphere in the $ n $-disc the left lifting property for all acyclic Serre fibrations?

I am looking for a reference for this proposition, or alternatively, for an argument. Indeed, one can find this proposition in Dwyer’s and Spalinski’s *Homotopy Theories and Model Categories*, p. 37, but without a proof.

Best wishes.

Comment: I'll just point out that it's possible to prove directly using basic facts about homotopy groups, but it takes some work. The proofs cited below involve slightly heavier machinery (mapping spaces, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the proof is non-trivial. The claim appears (with proof) as Theorem 2.4.12 in [Hovey, *Model categories*] and as part of Theorem 17.2.2 in [May and Ponto, *More concise algebraic topology*]. It is also asserted (without proof) as Lemma 9.4 in [Goerss and Jardine, *Simplicial homotopy theory*, Ch. I].